# "not declared in this scope" error with templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, g++, compiler-errors

Here is code sample which reproduces my problem:

```
template <typename myType>
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
protected:
    int myOption;
    virtual void set() = 0;
};

template <typename InterfaceType>
class ChildClass : public Base < std::vector<InterfaceType> >
{
public:
    ChildClass() {}
    virtual ~ChildClass() {}
 protected:
    virtual void set();
};

template <typename InterfaceType>
void ChildClass<InterfaceType>::set()
{
     myOption = 10;
}
```

My usage in `main()`:

```
ChildClass<int> myObject;
```

I get the following error (gcc 4.4.3 on ubuntu):

> ‘myOption’ was not declared in this scope

If my ChildClass would be without new template parameter this would work fine, i.e.:

```
class ChildClass : public Base < std::vector<SomeConcreteType> >
```

---

### Edit

I've managed to solve it, if my set method looks like:

```
Base<std::vector<InterfaceType> >::myOption = 10;
```

It works fine. Still though not sure why I need to specify all template parameters.

Comment: `myOption` is a dependent name, it will work with `this->`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`myOption` is not a dependent name, i.e. it doesn't depend on the template arguments explicitly so the compiler tries to look it up early. You must make it a dependent name:

```
template <typename InterfaceType>
void ChildClass<InterfaceType>::set()
{
     this->myOption = 10;
}
```

Now it depends on the type of `this` and thus on the template arguments. Therefore the compiler will bind it at the time of instantiation.

This is called [Two-phase name lookup](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#two-phase).

Comment: +1, I knew it but still missed it. :)

Comment: Might require another question, but is there a way to avoid having to refer to every base class variable by `this->myVar`? It makes the code ugly.

Comment: @JoeyDumont: I can't think of any. Defining a function named myOption() returning a reference to this->myOption will shorten this (no pun intended), but IMO will be even more ugly. Besides, I don't think `this->` is ugly at all. This is how you would write it in C, say.

Comment: @ybungalobill Fair enough, but my code mostly consists of equations, so having tons of this-> makes it a little less readable. It's not _that_ big of an issue, though, so I won't search any further.

Comment: It works without this in Visual Studio 2008, just myOption = 10; is OK.

Comment: @qub1n: it is not OK. It is Visual Studio 2008 which is not OK if it compiles this code. The authority that does specify what is correct C++ is ISO WG21, and it says that this program is invalid (see other answers for quotes).

Answer (score 19):

#### C++03 14.6.2 Dependent names

> In the definition of a class template or a member of a class template,
>   if a base class of the class template depends on a template-parameter,
>   the base class scope is ***not examined*** during unqualified name
>   lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or
>   member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

The following code should work.

```
template <typename InterfaceType>
void ChildClass<InterfaceType>::set()
{
   Base<std::vector<InterfaceType> >::myOption = 10;
}
```

Comment: (Rhetorical question) Great, but _why_?

Comment: @Eric: Better ;) A combination of your answer and ybungalobill's would be the perfect answer.